# VB.NET Change The Time of "StopWatch" Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, stopwatch

I Got StopWatch , And i want that the stopwatch start to count from `01:00:12,000`
my code(not works):

```
    Dim sp As New Stopwatch
    Dim lb As New Label
    Me.Controls.Add(lb)
    lb.Text = ""
    sp.Elapsed.Hours.Equals(1)
    sp.Elapsed.Minutes.Equals(0)
    sp.Elapsed.Seconds.Equals(12)
    sp.Elapsed.Milliseconds.Equals(0)
    sp.Start()
    lb.Text = sp.Elapsed.Hours.ToString & ":" & sp.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString & ":" & sp.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString & "," & sp.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString
```

Comment: What happens when you run the above?

Comment: the stopwatch is "00:00:00,000"

Comment: You could write a wrapper class which holds a stopwatch and has an initial time. It provides the same methods as `StopWatch` but the properties like `Elapsed` return the elapsed timespan + the initial offset timespan.

Comment: The `.Equals()` method doesn't work anything at all like what you expected. It's inherited from `Object` and **returns** a boolean that is true if the value of the property equals the argument. It doesn't assign or set anything.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Good that you corrected the misunderstanding, but actually it's not `Object.Equals` but [`Int32.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.equals.aspx).

Comment: True - Int32 overrides the object implementation. I guess I'm not sure of the correct terminology, but you could say something like that Object _originates_ the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

There is no way to initialize the `Stopwatch` class to anything but 0.

Nothing is stopping you from *adding* 1 hour and 12 seconds to the result though.

```
lb.Text = (sp.Elapsed.Hours + 1).ToString & ":" & sp.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString _
          & ":" & (sp.Elapsed.Seconds + 12).ToString & "," _
          & sp.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

The StopWatch doesn't work that way.  What you need to do is record the start time in a different variable and then add the Stopwatch's elapsed time to the start time

```
Dim StartTime AS Date = Date.Now
...

Dim EndTime AS Date = StartTime.AddMilliseconds(StopWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```